# Is it possible to read and assign variable in the same statement in tsql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using TSQL on SQL Server.
Is it possible to write a statement in which a temporary variable gets read and updated at the same time?
E.g. (assuming @var1 and var2 are defined)

```
select top 1 @var1 = field1, @var2 = field2 from table1 where field1 > @var1;
```

Or should it be split into:

```
select top 1 @var1 = field1, @var2 = field2 from table1 where field1 > @current_var1;
set current_var1 = @var1;
```

Could the former solution incur any concurrency problems? More generally, are there any issues about it? I looked into MSDN documentation but couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: The first query will provide deterministic results if you add `ORDER BY`. Remember SQL is set-based so the operation happens all-at-once logically; no need for additional variables or statements to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Aside: Valid in SQL Server is `update set @FooBefore = Foo, @FooAfter = Foo += @FooIncrement from FooTable where FooId = 42;`. Meaning: update the value of column `Foo` by adding `@FooIncrement` and return both the _before_ and _after_ values for the row in `FooTable` where `FooId` is [`42`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the specific case I was studying, after splitting the statement `select top 1 @var1 = field1, @var2 = field2 from table1 where field1 > @var1;` into two lines like

```
@currvar1 = @var1
select top 1 @var1 = field1, @var2 = field2 from table1 where field1 > @currvar1;
```

the problems vanished and the procedure started working like a charm.
It's worth mentioning that in the case I was studying, the statement was placed inside a while loop like this:

```
select @maxvar1 = max(field1) from table1
while @var1 < @maxvar1
    select top 1 @var1 = field1, @var2 = field2 from table1 where field1 > @var1;
```

I don't think the while loop can affect the behaviour, any way after changing it to

```
select @maxvar1 = max(field1) from table1
while @var1 < @maxvar1
    @currvar1 = @var1
    select top 1 @var1 = field1, @var2 = field2 from table1 where field1 > @currvar1;
```

it started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to read and assign variable in the same statement?

Yes, at least this is true at least some of the time. The below works as expected

```
DECLARE @number INT =  2147483647

SELECT @number = number
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE number <  @number
ORDER BY number

SELECT @number, @@ROWCOUNT
```

Even though after the first row is processed `-32768` is assigned to the variable the `WHERE` clause clearly still uses the initial value of `2147483647` rather than the new value - as the `@@ROWCOUNT` shows that it processed the whole table and `@number` ended up with the result of the final assignment .

So in this case the initial value of the variable was treated as a [runtime constant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions/) and not affected by the assignments. I doubt that this behaviour is guaranteed though. Generally the effect of variable assignment across multiple rows is not guaranteed.

I also tried the following to ensure that the variable was being evaluated RBAR and still the same result as above.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[F](@I1 INT,@I2 INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
RETURN @I1
END

GO
DECLARE @number INT =  2147483647
SELECT @number = number
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE number <  [dbo].[F](@number, number)
ORDER BY number

SELECT @number, @@ROWCOUNT
```

Comment: You described 3 different events that occur successively. Also, note how SQL Server treats variables at the time of the execution (Parameter Sniffing)